# How to use variable on mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
mdb.model('humans').find(name:/somethink/,function(e,users){
                console.log(e);
                console.log(users);
                uutils.sendReturn(res,users);
            });
```

how to use variable name:/somethink/

Comment: Can you explain more what exactly is your question  if you want to get variable dynamically  name: '/'+ somethink+'/'

Comment: i do it but its not work

Comment: post how you have tried ?

Comment: `mdb.model('humans').find({name:'/'+req.body.aranacak+'/'},function(e,users){
          console.log(e);
          console.log(users);
          uutils.sendReturn(res,users);
         });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do like operation in mongodb is $regex [See Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
  var reqName = req.body.aranacak;
    mdb.model('humans').find({ name: { $regex : reqName } } ,function(e,users){  
             console.log(e); 
             console.log(users);
                 uutils.sendReturn(res,users); 
    });
```